# Concerning the ring extension $A[a^{-1}] \subseteq B[a^{-1}] \subseteq C[a^{-1}]$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, integral-extensions

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero and let $A \subseteq B \subseteq C$ be three integral domains (= commutative rings without zero divisors) which are $k$-algebras. Denote the field of fractions of $C$ by $F$.

Let $a \in A-k$, so $A[a^{-1}] \subseteq B[a^{-1}] \subseteq C[a^{-1}] \subseteq F$.

Assume that $B[a^{-1}] = C[a^{-1}]$.

> Is there a 'mild' additional condition that guarantees that $B=C$?

Ideas for 'plausible' additional conditions: $A \subseteq C$ is an algebraic ring extension; $\dim(A)=\dim(B)=\dim(C)$ (Krull/GK dimension of rings or $A$-modules, etc.); $\{A,B,C\}$ are UFD's (perhaps helpful; please see the following example in which $B$ is not a UFD, but still $B=C$).

Example: $k[x^2] \subset k[x^2,x^3] \subset k[x]$ with $a=x$.

Remark: If I am not wrong, I have once showed that if $\{A,B,C\}$ are UFD's, then $B=C$. But I think I have also assumed flatness.

Any hints and comments are welcome!

Comment: Consider $k\left[x\right]\subseteq k\left[x\right]\subseteq k\left[x,x^{-1}\right]$: all these rings are UFDs but with $a=x$ you clearly don't have that $B=C$.

Comment: Do we need $A$ in the question?

Comment: Actually, using @TrevorGunn's comment,it looks like you could rephrase your question as follows: if $B\subseteq C$ and $b\in B$ is such that $B\left[b^{-1}\right]=C\left[b^{-1}\right]$, under what assumptions can we deduce that $B=C$?

Comment: Then, the condition on flatness for the extension $B\subseteq C$ is not enough: take any extension $B\subseteq B\left[b^{-1}\right]$ where $b\in\mathrm{Frac}(B)-B$. The same argument shows that the condition "$B$ and $C$ are UFDs" does not work.

Comment: Moreover, the condition "B is a UFD and C is integral over B" does the trick. I shall use the notations of my comment following the one of @Trevor. Indeed, let $c\in C$ and write $c=\beta/\gamma$ where $\beta,\gamma\in B$ with $\gamma$ and $\beta$ coprime (i.e. they share no common prime factor) and $\gamma$ divides some power of $b$: then, if $f$ is a monic polynomial over $B$ (say of degree $n$) such that $f(c)=0$, one checks, after clearing the denominators of the previous equality, that $\gamma$ divides $\beta^n$ hence $\gamma$ is invertible in $B$, so that $c$ lies in $B$.

Comment: @TrevorGunn, thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Gaussian, thank you very much for all your comments. (I apologize for the delay; I wanted to write to you on Nov 28).

Comment: @Gaussian, you may write your comments as an anwer, if you wish. Your comments are good. I am trying to weaken your condition: '$B \subseteq C$ is integral+ $B$ is a UFD' to '$B \subseteq C$ is integral + $B$ is a ...' I guess that ... could be GCD domain, though I wish an even weaker condition on $B$, but probably this should depend on a specific $B$ (and $C$).

Comment: If, for example, $C=B[c]$, for some $c \in C$, then maybe more can be said. It seems that only the minimal polynomial of $c$ over $B$ is of interest,  so it is enough to consider the particular $\beta$ and $\gamma$ such that $c=\beta/\gamma$.

Comment: We wish that $\gamma$ will have the property of a prime element (at least with respect to $\beta$), so that here $\gamma | \beta^n$ implies that $\gamma | \beta$, hence $\gamma \in k$ or $\gamma=\mu \beta$ (since $\gcd(\gamma,\beta)=1$). We see that $B$ should be a GCD domain, or at least $\gcd(\gamma,\beta)$ should exist ($\beta$ and $\gamma$ have uniqe decompositions, or all decompositions are coprime).